# Круговая маска CSS с переменной шириной границы

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Мне было бы интересно, есть ли способ сделать подобное изображение с помощью маскировки, как показано на рисунке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Синий эффект в левом верхнем углу не требуется. Я хочу получить маскировку круга.

*Примечание переводчика:*

Связанный вопрос: [Комбинированная SVG маска для растровых изображений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/994499/28748)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56300171/7394871

Comment: На мой взгляд отвечая на этот вопрос можно применить для ответа много разных техник решения. Принимаются любые ответы полностью отвечающие требованию в вопросе. Размещайте свои иные решения, плюсики и галочка ждут вас. Добавлю ещё тег JS

Answer (score 4):

Используйте два элемента с одинаковым фоном и отрегулируйте `background-size / background-position`, чтобы создать иллюзию этого эффекта:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1057/800/800);
  background-size:auto 220px;
  background-position:top left;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:inherit;
  background-position:bottom left;
  border-radius:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

```css
.box {
  --b:-20px; /* Нижняя часть псевдоэлемента*/
  --l:10px;  /* Слева от псевдоэлемента*/
  --s:2; /*размер псевдоэлемента (как масштабный коэффициент)*/
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1057/800/800);
  background-size:auto calc(100% - var(--b));
  background-position:top left;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:var(--b);
  left:var(--l);
  width:calc(100%/var(--s));
  height:calc(100%/var(--s));
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:auto calc(100%*var(--s) - var(--b));
  background-position:bottom 0 left calc(-1 * var(--l));
  border-radius:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--s:3;l:50px;"></div>

<div class="box" style="--s:1.5;l:50px;--b:-10px"></div>
```

И вы можете легко добавить границы:

```css
.box {
  --b:-20px; /* Bottom of the pseudo element*/
  --l:10px;  /* Left of the pseudo element*/
  --s:2; /*size of the pseudo element (as a scale factor)*/
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1057/800/800);
  background-size:auto calc(100% - var(--b));
  background-position:top left;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid dodgerblue;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:var(--b);
  left:var(--l);
  width:calc(100%/var(--s));
  height:calc(100%/var(--s));
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:auto calc(100%*var(--s) - var(--b));
  background-position:bottom 0 left calc(-1 * var(--l));
  border-radius:inherit;
  border:inherit;
  box-sizing:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:3;l:50px;">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:1.5;l:50px;--b:-10px">

</div>
```