# Комбинированная SVG маска для растровых изображений

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

> **Это не перевод**, разработка вопроса и ответов авторские. Здесь вы найдёте подробное описание интересных возможностей  в использовании и анимировании
>   масок SVG, освоив которые, вы сможете реализовать свой, оригинальный
>   дизайн веб страничек.

Вопрос инспирирован топиком: [Круговая маска CSS
 с переменной шириной
 границы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/994151/28748)

В ответе на тот вопрос были использованы правила `CSS`
А как сделать тоже самое с помощью `SVG`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понятно, что нужно использовать маски SVG.

У меня получилось с помощью маски вырезать круг:

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 1400 788" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    <g fill="white">
       <!-- Круговая маска --> 
    <circle cx="700" cy="392" r="300" />
  </g>
 </mask>
 </defs>    

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUiPo.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
   
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Вопросы**

1. Как сделать маску для более сложной формы?
2. Как добавить к маске белые сегменты обводки?
3. Можно ли анимировать маску, обводку окружностей?

Answer (score 4):

Для получения нужной формы добавляем в маску вторую окружность меньшего диаметра

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1400 788" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    <g fill="white">
       <!-- Center circle --> 
    <circle cx="700" cy="392" r="300"  />
    <!-- Left circle -->
   <circle cx="520" cy="620" r="120" />
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs>    

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUiPo.jpg"" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
   
</svg>  
</div>
```

- В маске `<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />`

прямоугольник перекрывает всё изображение. Красный цвет закраски прямоугольника - `fill="red"` занимает промежуточное значение между белым цветом, что придаёт маске полную прозрачность и чёрным цветом, который делает маску полностью непрозрачной. Поэтому остальная часть картинки становится полупрозрачной
см. топик [Практические примеры применения масок svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748)

- Окружности в маске имеют окраску белого цвета, поэтому эта область
  становится полностью прозрачной.

**Создание белых сегментов окружностей**

- Для этого нужно сделать некоторые расчёты:

Длина окружности при радиусе `300px` равна: `2 * 3.4115 * 300 = 1884,9px`

Нам нужен сектор длиной примерно (визуально по картинке) в одну восьмую часть
 `1884,9 / 8 = 235.5px`

- Для отрисовки сектора применим атрибут `stroke-dasharray`

`stroke-dasharray="235.5 1648.5"`, где первый параметр длина черточки, второй параметр длина пробела.

Для второй окружности делаем точно такие же расчеты, но для радиуса `120px`

- Добавляем атрибуты `stroke-dasharray` к окружностям в маске и
  закрашиваем обводку в чёрный цвет. Это сделает сегменты
  непрозрачными, после применения маски сегменты окружности будут
  белого цвета

Для позиционирования сегмента сдвигаем его начало командой `stroke-dashoffset`

`stroke-dashoffset="400"`

**Собираем всё вместе:**

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1400 788" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    <g fill="white">
       <!-- Center circle --> 
    <circle cx="700" cy="392" r="300"  stroke="#151515"  stroke-width="17"  
   stroke-dasharray="235.5 1648.5" stroke-dashoffset="400" />
    <!-- Left circle -->
   <circle cx="520" cy="620" r="120" stroke="#151515"  stroke-width="12"  
   stroke-dasharray="114.245 639.96" stroke-dashoffset="434"  />
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs>    

     <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUiPo.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
   </svg>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### SVG анимации

**#1.**   Вращение сегментов окружности

Применяется команда анимации `stroke-dashoffset` сдвига начала сегмента.

- Сначала вращается сегмент малого круга, условие запуска анимации
  `begin="svg1.click"` - клик по любой части SVG полотна
- После окончания первой анимации начинается вращение сегмента большого
  круга.
  Условие запуска - `begin="an2.end"`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1400 788" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    <g fill="white">
       <!-- Center circle --> 
    <circle id="circleBig" cx="700" cy="392" r="300"  stroke="#151515"  stroke-width="17"  
       stroke-dasharray="235.5 1648.5" stroke-dashoffset="400" pointer-events="none" >
       <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an2.end" dur="6s" values="400;-1484.8" repeatCount="1"  restart="whenNotActive" />
  </circle>
    <!-- Left circle -->
   <circle cx="520" cy="620" r="120" stroke="#151515"  stroke-width="12"  
        stroke-dasharray="114.245 639.96" stroke-dashoffset="434"  > 
       <animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" values="434;-320"    repeatCount="2" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </circle>
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs>    

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUiPo.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
 </svg>  
</div>
```

**#2.** Вращение малой окружности маски

Координаты вращения малой окружности это координаты центра большой окружности.
Команда анимации вращения :

```
<animateTransform id="an2T" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="0 700 392;-180 700 392;90 700 392;0 700 392"    repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" />
```

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1400 888" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    <g fill="white">
       <!-- Center circle --> 
    <circle id="circleBig" cx="700" cy="392" r="300"  stroke="#151515"  stroke-width="17"  
       stroke-dasharray="235.5 1648.5" stroke-dashoffset="400" pointer-events="none" >
       <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="400;-1484.8" repeatCount="1"  restart="whenNotActive" />
  </circle> 
    <!-- small circle -->
   <circle cx="520" cy="620" r="120"> 
       <animateTransform id="an2T" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="0 700 392;-180 700 392;90 700 392;0 700 392"    repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </circle>
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs>    

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUiPo.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
  
</svg>  
</div>
```

**#3.** Увеличение размеров малой окружности

Достигается анимацией изменения радиуса окружности

```
<animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="120;60;120" /> 
           <animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="1s" values="434;-320"    repeatCount="8" restart="whenNotActive" />
```

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1400 888" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    <g fill="white">
       <!-- Big circle --> 
    <circle id="circleBig" cx="700" cy="392" r="300"  stroke="#151515"  stroke-width="17"  
       stroke-dasharray="235.5 1648.5" stroke-dashoffset="400" pointer-events="none" >
       <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="400;-1484.8" repeatCount="1"  restart="whenNotActive" />
  </circle> 
    <!-- Small circle -->
   <circle cx="520" cy="620" r="120" stroke="#151515"  stroke-width="12"  
        stroke-dasharray="114.245 639.96" stroke-dashoffset="434"  > 
 
      <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="120;60;120" /> 
     <animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="1s" values="434;-320"    repeatCount="8" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </circle>
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs>    

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUiPo.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
  
</svg>  
</div>
```

[Live Demo](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/full/Yopgbr)